# Ckeditor removes html5 video block during initialization

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, html5-video, contenteditable

I have div contenteditable with video
After initialization ckeditor video disappears.

I tried ckeditor4 and ckeditor5 inline 11.2.0 All scripts in my local server, not cdn. Browser Firefox anf chrome

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    <video src="[realy correct path to video]" controls></video>
</div>
<script>
    ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) );
</script>
```

As a result, I get this:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the general rule in CKEditor 5 is that, without a plugin which handles a specific HTML element, class, style or attribute, that HTML "thing" will be filtered out by the editor. Unlike in CKEditor 4, the `allowedContent` option does not exist because you cannot enable more HTML "things" than what the currently loaded plugins handle. This is most likely a reason why video tag has been lost.

Please also see: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#why-does-the-editor-filter-out-my-content-styles-classes-elements-where-is-configallowedcontent-true